# How to compare users input to list using tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I'm trying to figure out a way to compare a users input to an array. If the users input is unique, and doesn't match any of the elements in the list, it should add the input to the list. All my methods have not worked so far. Below is my most recent

```
def input_stub():
    global player_num
    global name_entry
    global display_num
    if player_num != t1_amount:     ##t1_amount is the amount of elements the user wants in the list
        t1_input = Toplevel(master)
        final_confirm.withdraw()
        title = Label(t1_input, text = "Team 1 Input").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        request = Label(t1_input, text = "Please enter player " + str(display_num) + " name").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        name_entry = Entry(t1_input)
        name_entry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        display_num = display_num + 1
        valid_button = Button(t1_input, text = "Submit", command = lambda: player_valid()).grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        def player_valid():              ##THIS IS WHERE USER INPUT NEEDS TO BE COMPARED
            elem = len(team_1_array)
            for i in range(0, elem):
                p = None
                while not p or p in team_1_array:
                    p = name_entry.get()
                    if p in team_1_array:
                        error = Label(t1_input, text = "Error").grid(row = 3, column = 1)
                    else:
                        player_num = player_num + 1
                        t1_validation(team_1_array)  ##IF IT PASSES, IT MOVES ON TO BEING PUT ONTO THE END OF THE LIST
        def t1_validation(current_team):
            global player_num
            global display_num
            global team_1_array
            global t1_confirm
            current_player_trans = p
            current_team.append(current_player_trans)
            if player_num != t1_amount:
                t1_input.destroy()
                input_stub()
            elif player_num == t1_amount:    ##THIS DISPLAYES THE LIST ONCE THE SELECTED AMOUNT OF ELEMENTS ARE IN THE ARRAY
                t1_confirm = Toplevel(master)
                t1_input.withdraw()
                t1_confirm.geometry("200x200")
                player_count = 1
                for i in range(len(team_1_array)):
                    exec('Label%d=Label(t1_confirm,text="%s")\nLabel%d.pack()' % (i, "Player " + str(player_count) + " : " + team_1_array[i], i))
                    player_count = player_count + 1
                confirm_button = Button(t1_confirm, text = "Confirm Team 1", command = lambda: input_stub_2()).pack()
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why do you think this isn't working? What does the code do that isn't what you expect?

Comment: @BryanOakley The program does not move onto the next input window once I click the valid_button. It either stays there or crashes

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that your function is being called? Have you verified `p=name_entry.get()` is returning what you expect? What else have you tried to do?

Comment: @BryanOakley it did save the entry in P, but the submit button `valid_button` doesn't even do anything now, I did add a flag below `def player_valid()` and it does go off

Comment: Put a `print()` one different lines and try to find out which lines prints and where the code breaks.

Comment: @CoolCloud I did this before posting, it enters the function, but never enters the for loop

Comment: So I guess you are checking for `True` in the list, right?

Comment: I’m comparing users inputs and seeing if that input already exists in the list